# how to retain the user control values in Wizard control using jquery

Tags: jquery, wizard

I have a user control attached to one of the wizard steps of wizard control. The problem is the values is lost when I clicked te Next and Previous Button. Any help how to retain the values using jquery?

Web form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>  
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                       <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
     <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" HeaderText="Simple Example of Wizard Control" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Larger" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Crimson" OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">  
            <WizardSteps >  
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizadStep1" runat="server" title="Personal Information" >  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Your Name" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1"></asp:Label>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    <br />  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="City" AssociatedControlID="TextBox2"></asp:Label>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                </asp:WizardStep>  
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" title="Favorite Color?">  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Favorite Color?" AssociatedControlID="RadioButtonList1"></asp:Label>  
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">  
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Red</asp:ListItem>  
                        <asp:ListItem>Green</asp:ListItem>  
                        <asp:ListItem>Blue</asp:ListItem>  
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>  
                </asp:WizardStep>  
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" title="Favorite Tool?">  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Most Favorite?" AssociatedControlID="RadioButtonList2"></asp:Label>  
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">  
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Asp.Net</asp:ListItem>  
                        <asp:ListItem>ColdFusion</asp:ListItem>  
                        <asp:ListItem>PHP</asp:ListItem>  
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>  
                    <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" id="WebUserControl1" />
                </asp:WizardStep>  
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep4" runat="server" Title="Result" OnActivate="WizardStep4_Activate">  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="DarkGoldenrod"></asp:Label>  
                </asp:WizardStep>  
            </WizardSteps>  
        </asp:Wizard>  
    </div>
                           </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

User Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebUserControl1" %>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/><span id="0">Column1</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/><span id="1">Column 2</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/><span id="2">Column 3</span></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```